# How to find element based on text and class with Selenium?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have an html table, and I want to find the `td` element in `tbody` based on the text  and if it doesn't contain a certain class. It should ignore anything in `thead` even if the text is present.

```
...

<div id="mytable">
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>....</tr>
              ...
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="inactive">3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

...
```

Here is the code:

```
def do_click(user_input):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(url)

    mytable_div = browser.find_element_by_id("mytable")
    element = mytable_div.find_element_by_xpath("//div/table/tbody/td[contains(text()='%s')]" % user_input)

    if element:
        element.click()
```

So if the `user_input = 3`, the table element **should NOT** be clicked because it has the class `inactive` even though the text is present.

If the `user_input = 4`, then the table element **should** be clicked since it does not have a inactive class and the text is present.

Currently the code doesn't work because my xpath expression is invalid, but I'm not sure what the correct way to check for both the class and the text would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) is a function and expects 2 arguments to be passed in - a string where to look and a substring - what to look. Fix your expression:

```
"//div/table/tbody//td[contains(text(), '%s')]" % user_input
```

You can also use a dot instead of `text()` in this case.

And, to also check for the class being not `inactive`, add "not contains" check:

```
"//div/table/tbody//td[contains(., '%s')][not(contains(@class, 'inactive'))]" % user_input
```

As for the logic, handle the [`NoSuchElementException`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException) exception which, if raised, would mean the element was not found, click the element if no exception was raised:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    element = mytable_div.find_element_by_xpath("//div/table/tbody//td[contains(., '%s')][not(contains(@class, 'inactive'))]" % user_input)
    element.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Element not found")
```

Comment: How do I prevent clicking if the `td` element has the class `inactive`?

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason the xpath returns an error: `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div/table/tbody/td[contains(., '4')][not(contains(@class, 'inactive'))]"}`. **However**, I am able to find and click it directly with `//div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]`. It seems like the element is definitely there, but the xpath isn't picking up on it.